# From within a bash, bat, or powershell script is it possible to get the last IM message sent to you within Lync?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, lync

I use Outlook and Lync 2013. I have msys bash installed, and I have a script that runs a while(1) loop that sends Growl notifications whenever an IM is sent (it reads the ugly Lync log files).

I'd like to include the message itself. These aren't stored in the log file, nor is it possible to do network adapter sniffing (since it's encrypted on the wire itself).

Outlook stores IM conversations in the most horrendous fashion possible, and doesn't seem to consistently save them (stored conversations seemed to only be saved a few times a day or not even that often, with each having overlapping pieces).

Is there any facility or method to retrieve these?

Comment: I haven't ever timed it to be sure, but I think the timing of archiving messages to Outlook is probably more reliable than you think - it's just not based on any static timeline. It appears to archive a conversation history after a certain amount of inactivity in the conversation. It doesn't matter if it's been a single message since the last archive or dozens - after the inactivity timeout, a log is saved. Why there's overlap is beyond me. I can only guess it's saving the entire contents of the window every time.